# Smoothly Move userobjects in a Powerbuilder window

Tags: powerbuilder

I am using Powerbuilder 10.5 and have built a window which uses openuserobject to display some custom visual userobjects.

I have managed to use drag/drop events to move my userobjects around the window area but I would prefer a smoother way which would also display the dragged object while it's being moved to its new position. Default drag/drop behavior only displays an icon during drag.

Is there any way I can resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might try this old trick used to move windows without titlebars.

```
[Instance declaration]
CONSTANT uint WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 161
CONSTANT uint HTCAPTION = 2

[mousedown event on the userobject]
Post( Handle( this ), WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, Long( xpos, ypos ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it seems that the "DragWithin" event did the trick although it's not super smooth.

I used obj.move(x,y) in my dragwithin event and problem solved!